# Why is error message SQL Conversion failed (date) in some instances, but not others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've run into a very odd issue with a SQL query where I receive the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." unexpectedly (well I didn't expect it) but with different manipulations of the query some work, but others do not.  So I have a working solution, but I want to understand why some paths do not work and some do.

Background: myTable is a table with myDateAsString which holds dates as strings in the dd/mm/yyyy format.  I'm unable to change this or change the database structure in anyway, but want to pull some data out as dates to process.

Initial Data Extraction: This works (but doesn't have the desired WHERE clause to narrow data (I'd expect if there was data that wouldn't convert it would throw an error here)

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, myDateAsString, 103) as myDate
FROM   myTable
```

Addition of WHERE Clause: I only want to pull data that is "in the future"; since the query above works I'd expect this to work as well, but it throws an error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

```
SELECT *
FROM (
     SELECT CONVERT(date, myDateAsString, 103) as myDate
     FROM   myTable) as ConvertedData
WHERE myDate > GETDATE()
```

Is there an reason this fails?  The data all looks to be correct dates (particularly as the "initial data extraction" query above doesn't fail.

To a Common Table Expression: it seemed (from searches) that the above might fail based on execution order etc... so I thought CTE's to the rescue and attempted the following

```
WITH ConvertedData_CTE (myDate)
AS
(
   SELECT CONVERT(date, myDateAsString, 103) as myDate
   FROM   myTable
)

SELECT *
FROM   ConvertedData_CTE
WHERE myDate > GETDATE()
```

Again the error message "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." (note: if I remove the WHERE clause no error message)

One more attempt: so I then tried with a table variable as such

```
DECLARE @ConvertedData TABLE (myDate date)

INSERT INTO @CovertedData (myDate)
SELECT CONVERT(date, myDateAsString, 103) as myDate
FROM   myTable

SELECT *
FROM   @ConvertedDate
WHERE  myDate > GETDATE()
```

And to my surprise, this worked.

So my question is why does the last query work, but the CTE and inner select not work?  It just seems a bit counter intuitive to me as I'd expect them all to work, but would like to better understand why some do and some do not.

### EDIT: addition of sample data

Sample Data

> 22/08/2013 
>   10/03/2012 
>   22/08/2013 
>   24/08/2013 
>   27/08/2013 
>   21/08/2013
>   23/08/2013 
>   15/03/2013 
>   07/04/2010 
>   22/08/2013
>   '  /  /    '

note: the data in the original table has 3394 rows and if I select the first 1010 rows I can get all the queries to work; this data represents rows 1010 to 1020 where if I limit on the original table it works as described ... however if I create a new table with just this data ... then the queries all work
(this sort of makes sense to me as that is what is kind of happening in the queries; i.e. the new table, the table-variable, works but the other methods do not)
hope that points in some sort of good direction

EDIT: additional information, initially not provided for clarity
The above queries all have an additional WHERE clause on them as some data in the database (that should clearly be stored as NULL) is stored as '  /  /    '
So there is an additional WHERE myDateAsString <> '  /  /    ' on all the above queries
note: I've update the sample data to include that data item as well, oddly the queries still work (only one "bad data point" and a the <> clause in there is excluding) ... question still is why excluding works on the SELECT, where the convert occurs, but then errors on the WHERE with GETDATE(), which would be after the conversion is completed?

Comment: This all stems from the poor decision of storing dates as strings. If you stored dates as dates none of this would be an issue.

Comment: Your issue is because when you use GetDate() that is datetime, in your second query it does not work because it loks like myDate is a string you cant compare a string to a DateTime.  In your final one it appears to work because in your @ConvertedDate table your value in the table is just a DATE, not DateTime.    The underlying issue is that myDate you keep converting to just date, not dateTime which is what GetDate() Is

Comment: @Brad But the conversion error seems to imply that the character data can't be converted at all to anything, either date or datetime.

Comment: Then the data in the table is not valid to convert to the date properly.  You can check out @TimBiegeleisen s answer below to find bad data, but the way you are using it maybe change his query to use DATE  in the convert instead of DATETIME

Comment: @sean but that I could ... if I had control of the storage of data I wouldn't have this issue at all, but as I do not (third party data storage) I have to look for another solution (which I have in the last query, just trying to understand SQL better and why the other queries do not work (as they seem similar / equivalent) to me

Comment: @Brad ... while it is disappointing that the data is stored as a string; the conversion to date succeeds (see first query above where there is no error raised); however when I put a where clause (to then compare those successfully converted dates) I then get the error message (hence my confusion) ... all further evidenced by the last query works (more confusion), but if it were bad data the last query wouldn't work either

Comment: Can you post the table structure and some data examples

Comment: You've answered the question yourself. The bad data is causing the trouble. The where clause was preventing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that some of your text date data is either corrupted, or is in a format which can't be converted to a date.  To flush out such records, you may try using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, myDateAsString) IS NULL;
```

Once you have found the troublesome rows, you should fix your data, convert the column to a date type, and then stop storing date information as plain text.

Comment: This is where the oddness appears to me, there is no data that shows up here (note: I had to use TRY_CONVERT(datetime, myDateAsTring, 103) due to the odd formatting, but no data show up as troublesome here) ... my first assumption was some bad rows, but then I would have expected the "initial data extraction" query to fail as well, but it succeeds

Comment: My answer is falling short here.  Please add sample data to your question which makes your problem reproducible.  Then, someone else or I can look into it.

Comment: I've added some sample data, but the caveat seems to be that if I create a whole new table with just that sample data then everything works; if I pull only that data from the existing table (i.e. subset of 10 rows) then it fails as above ... some other issue with the table setup or settings or construction?

Comment: Please try using `TRY_CONVERT` in your query instead of `CONVERT`.  And, you should _not_ have to pass anything to that function other than `datetime` as the 1st parameter, and the string date as the second parameter.

Comment: Tim! OK, so that works ... if I update the two failing queries with TRY_CONVERT (with or without the 103) it looks to work as expected ... do you have any idea why (say in the CTE example) it would work with TRY_CONVERT and not CONVERT (as the where clause is taking out the data that wouldn't CONVERT, we are not getting an error on the CONVERT, just when we use the outcome of the CONVERT to compare)

Comment: So here's the thing, `TRY_CONVERT` will (I think) try _every_ possible format/conversion which SQL Server knows.  You were using format mask 103, but if some of your data were not amenable to that, then it would fail.  On the other hand, `TRY_CONVERT` is a bit more robust.  But the moral of the story here is to _not_ store date information as text.  Please don't do that again, unless you want to start another discussion festival on Stack Overflow :~(

Comment: The tricky part here is that I have no control over the database; were that the case I would be able to change the structure; it is the oddness of having to work with third-party products in some cases :( Thanks for all your help ... I still think there is a bit unexplained (around the why) but seems to be a bit more around how it all works and unexpected data [insert hand-waving and misdirection] that might be too hard to get to the bottom of (if I can consistently recreate in a new database I'll think about re-posting :)